# Installation on old laptop results in boot failure "HDD is Failed"

Tags: boot, 20.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20:10 on an old core i3 2 core laptop, using the following steps:

1. Created Live ISO DVD
2. Put the DVD in the laptop
3. Allow it to erase everything for a clean install
4. Installation completes and I reboot (after removing the DVD)

On reboot I get the error "HDD is failed"

The laptop has no UEFI, so not sure that is the problem? I can run Ubuntu up by using the try it out feature on the DVD

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the hard drive itself isn't actually bad? Have you run a `fsck` (File System Check) on the disk to check its viability? You can do this from the Live DVD 

Comment: The disk was happily running Windows 10 prior. But I also tried it with a second disk and get the same issue. I'll try the fsck from live DVE

Comment: sudo fsck /dev/sdb3 returns no issues

Comment: In the live view, I can also mount the HDD and have a look round without issue

Comment: doing a sudo fdisk l show three disk, SDB1, 2 and 3 of types: "BIOS boot", "EFI System","Linux filesystem" if that's of any use

Answer (score 0):

Creating a USB installation using Ubuntu 18.04 and Rufus (which provides BIOS/UEFI as a boot option) has fixed the problem